# Setting Breeze Navigation Property in Knockout subscription

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, breeze, navigation-properties

I am building a SPA (Single Page Application) using Breezejs and Knockoutjs.

I am running into an issue when **trying to set a navigation property inside a knockout subscription**. On the final line of the `ko.subscription` the `console.log` function shows me the entity, however, the `WebPresences` navigation property is null.

Not sure if the fact its in a `ko.subscription` really matters but I've been able to set the navigation prop just in a js function I call right before save, so I think it has some significance.

So here is my `Entity` Model

```
public partial class Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> WebId { get; set; }

    public virtual WebPresence WebPresence { get; set; }
}
```

And here is my `ko.subscription` and relevant variables:

```
var vm = {
    newEntity: ko.observable(datacontext.createBreezeEntity('Entity')),
    newWebPresence: ko.observable(datacontext.newBreezeEntity('WebPresence')),
}

vm.newEntity().WebPresence.subscribe(
    function (data) {
        var self = this;
        if (data === null)
            self.target(vm.newWebPresence());
        console.log(vm.newEntity());
    }
);
```

And last but not least my `datacontext`

```
createBreezeEntity: function (entityName) {
    return manager.createEntity(entityName);
},

newBreezeEntity: function (entityName) {
    return manager.metadataStore.getEntityType(entityName).createEntity();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand what you're striving to accomplish.

One thing I'm pretty confident about ... is that your the `datacontext.newBreezeEntity` creates an object that is just hanging in thin air and isn't part of any navigation property.

Let's look at your `datacontext.newBreezeEntity` method:

```
return manager.metadataStore.getEntityType(entityName).createEntity();
```

This indeed does create a new entity of the type named `entityName`. But this is a 'proto-entity'. It does not belong to an `EntityManager` ... certainly not to the `manager` instance. It isn't related to any particular other entity (e.g., your mysteriously-named `Entity` entity). It's just a detached entity.

I'm betting you thought that it would belong to `manager` because you started the expression there. Well it doesn't. You lost the connection with `manager` the moment you asked for its `metadataStore`.

But there is so much else that makes no sense to me at all. I can't tell why you're subscribing to `vm.newBreezeEntity` nor why it's called "newBreezeEntity" nor what it's relationship is supposed to be to `vm.newEntity` nor what you think `this` is within the subscription function.

Perhaps you should step back and describe what you WANT this code to do.

Comment: I could try to explain my code and what I have done, however, you have already answered a much larger question. I have bigger problems if another person cannot come in, look at my code, and understand what is going on. I appreciate your response. I will come up with a better solution AND make my code more 'readable'. Thank you.